# SSL connection works with mysql client but not perl DBI:MariaDB

Tags: perl, ssl, mariadb, dbi

I have a MariaDB server set up with self-signed certificates to connect using TLS. This works when I connect with the corresponding client

```
$ mysql -u xxxx -h xx.xx.xx.xx -p 
\s shows:
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.37-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)     
SSL:   Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
```

The .my.cnf contains:

```
$ cat ~/.my.cnf 
[client]
ssl-cert=/---path-deleted---/client-cert.pem
ssl-key=/---path-deleted---/client-key.pem
```

Problem: I don't manage to connect from a Perl script with these settings. Without SSL, the script works. As soon as I enable SSL in the script (and enforce it on the server), I get:

```
failed: SSL connection error: ASN: bad other signature confirmation
```

When I check the certificates with openssl, I get

```
$ openssl verify ca-cert.pem client-cert.pem server-cert.pem 

error 18 at 0 depth lookup: self signed certificate
```

The certificates are indeed self-signed, and I want to keep it that way.

If I use "mariadb_ssl_verify_server_cert=0", I get

```
failed: SSL connection error: Enforcing SSL encryption is not supported without mariadb_ssl_verify_server_cert=1
```

What do I need to change to have a TLS-connection working from Perl?

I copy the lines of code I have in my connect sub for reference. A very similar code used to work on an older system with mysql (not mariadb), using just mysql_ssl=1 IIRC:

```
$self->{dsn} = "DBI:MariaDB:database=$database;host=$db_host;mariadb_ssl=1;".
    "mariadb_ssl_verify_server_cert=1;".
    "mariadb_ssl_ca_file=/---path---/ca-key.pem;".
    "mariadb_ssl_client_key=/---path---/client-key.pem;".
    "mariadb_ssl_client_cert=/---path---/client-cert.pem";
$self->{dbh} = DBI->connect($self->{dsn}, $db_user, $db_passwd,
            {'RaiseError' => 1, 'PrintError' => 1, AutoCommit => 1});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, albeit using DBI:mysql.
Issue was that I specified the IP address in the connection string rather than the servername, as specified in the SSL certificate CN. The mysql command line client didn't mind, but DBI:mysql does.

To get the CN of the certificate, I used openssl as per https://serverfault.com/a/931652/243186

I then needed to add an entry in my /etc/hosts file such that the CN matched the IP of the interface I was connecting to.

An alternate solution would have been for the MySQL server owner to have generated an SSL SAN cert specifying all possible servernames and IPs it could be connected to as.